# Unable to filter database results correctly

Tags: php, mysql, oop, model-view-controller

So I am making a system that manages users and I implemented a 'recycling bin' as a sanity check before permanently deleting a record.

I did this by adding a bool (tinyint) called `deleted` to my table.

This is the method I made to fetch the records:

```
static public function select_all($deleted = null) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM ".static::$db_table;
    if ($deleted) {
        $query .= " WHERE deleted = ".$deleted;
    }
    return static::sql_query($query);
}
```

`$db_table` is defined in the class and `sql_query($query)` is the method that actually executes the query, there is nothing wrong with those as I use them in every class and with every query.

This is how I call the method:

**Not deleted:**

```
$users = User::select_all(false);
```

- **Expected output:** All records which have `deleted` set to 0
- **Actual output:** Every single record

**Deleted:**

```
$users = User::select_all(true);
```

- **Expected output:** All records which have `deleted` set to 1
- **Actual output:** All records which have `deleted` set to 1

This is how I display the results:

```
<?php foreach ($users as $user) { ?>
    <?php if ($user->id != $_SESSION['user_id']) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= h($user->name()); ?></td>
            <td><?= h($user->email); ?></td>
            <td><?= h($user->username); ?></td>
            <td><?= h($user->status()); ?></td>
            <td>
                <a href="<?= url('users/details.php?id='.h(u($user->id))); ?>">Details</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

`h()` is a shortcut for `htmlspecialchars()` and`()` is a shortcut for `urlencode()`.

So basically, it is able to find all deleted users but not all non-deleted users.
Could anybody help me out please? I will provide any necessary additional information.

Comment: Think you need to use 1/0 instead of true/false for searching. (`.($deleted?1:0);` may do it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if statement is preventing you from adding the condition to SQL. Try if/else instead:

```
static public function select_all($deleted = null) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM ".static::$db_table;
    if (null !== $deleted) {
        if ($deleted) {
            $query .= " WHERE deleted = 1";
        } else {
            $query .= " WHERE deleted = 0";
        }
    }
    return static::sql_query($query);
}
```

**Update**
If you want it to work with tables without the deleted flag then you can add a check for `null`. See the updated code...

Comment: Problem is that as `$deleted = null` - if no value is passed it will look for deleted records.  Although this is the main problem.

Comment: The reason it's null by default is because I also have tables without a 'deleted' flag, so I also need to be able to call select_all() without parameters.

Comment: You could add an extra `if ($deleted != null)` level to this solution.

Comment: @NigelRen Edited the solution